# How can I retrieve a configuration programmatically on a JunOS device?

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos

this is a part of the configuration of Juniper Router, it stands the vlans:

```
     family inet {
                address 3.189.239.238/29;
                address 3.189.239.254/28;
            }
        }
        unit 472 {
            vlan-id 472;
            family inet;
        }
        unit 473 {
            vlan-id 473;
            family inet;
        }
        unit 474 {
            vlan-id 474;
            family inet {
                address 3.57.110.6/29;
            }
---(more 54%)---

        }
        unit 475 {
            vlan-id 475;
            family inet {
                address 3.57.110.14/29;
            }
        }
        unit 476 {
            vlan-id 476;
            family inet {
                address 3.57.110.22/29;
            }
        }
        unit 480 {
            vlan-id 480;
            family inet {
                address 1.246.212.14/28;
            }
```

how can it provide like a API out? then I can get all the vlan information from a website.

is there any way like SNMP protocol to provide the vlan information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

You can do a '`show configuration | display xml`' to get an XML output from the router.

Another, probably better option would be to use [netconf](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/netconf-edit-system-services.html), which uses the XML representation mentioned before.

If you want to use an API, I suggest you check out [PyEZ](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-pyez/information-products/pathway-pages/junos-pyez-developer-guide.html), a python library which allows you to communicate with a Juniper device using netconf. It offers some nice abstractions which makes scripting easier.

Another possibility, if you're mostly looking for configuration management tooling, could be [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com). Juniper has some nice [Ansible modules](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/product/en_US/ansible-for-junos-os) available.

Personally, I wouldn't invest in doing things with SNMP unless I really had to these days (and even then I'd probably refuse ;-)). There are many better options available.